# Why Group By Makes Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have sql query which like this

```
SELECT  XX.ARTICLE_ID,XX.ARTICLE_NAME
WHERE art.configuration_ID  in ( 1014  )
--Some long Code
```

this code runs fine it has 20000 records but the result show up even the query is not finish

My problem is when Im adding an aggregate function like this

```
    SELECT   XX.ARTICLE_ID, XX.ARTICLE_NAME,
            SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT, art.search_cnt + art.faq_cnt + art.browse_topic_cnt + art.hierarchical_tree_cnt + art.useful_item_cnt + art.guided_help_cnt))
        FROM  egssr_smy_article art  

-- Some Code
GROUP BY XX.ARTICLE_ID,XX.ARTICLE_NAME
```

The problem is when with the aggregate function I am force to use group by the problem is it the query runs 20 mins up and still no response is there anyway to solve this problem did I miss something? We have a records of almost 30000 and I have aggreate function sum which will be group based on article_id and name.

Comment: Try adding an index on the ArticleName column.

Comment: how do I achieve that?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=adding+an+index+on+the+column